# Lerp background colour based on time of day

Tags: javascript, time, colors, p5.js

I have been developing a small web project which displays the time and uses p5.js to animate a sun and moon to rotate in the background. The issue that I am having is implementing a gradual transition from one background(Sky) colour to another.

```
function setColours(){
 var pallete = [color(0),color(232, 131, 72),color(88,52,133),color(45, 221, 227)]
 var cMin = slider.value();
 hr = cMin / 60;
 //lerpAmt = map(mn,0,1440,0,1);
 console.log(hr);

 if(hr <= 4 || hr >= 20) { 
   background(pallete[0])//black
 } 

 else if(hr >5 && hr <= 6){
   background(232, 131, 72)//orange
 } 

 else if(hr >18 && hr <=19){
   background(232, 131, 72)
 }

 else if(hr >4 && hr <= 5){
   background(88,52,133) //purple    
 } 

 else if(hr > 19 && hr <= 20){
   background(88,52,133)       
 }

 else if(hr >= 7|| hr <18){
   background(45, 221, 227) //blue
 }
}
```

Above is the function that sets the sky colour on the page. the starting(0) position of the cycle is at the top and rotates counter-clockwise going from.

black -> purple -> orange -> blue -> orange -> purple -> black

initially, I started by lerping the colour by normalizing the minutes past the hour, this resulted in the sky colour transitioning between black and purple every hour and that once past 8PM(20:00) the background would continue to lerp to purple even though midnight is black. this has made me question if the logic for getting the time is any good.

1. is there a better way to check if it's currently between two hours?
2. how could I get the number of minutes until the next segment (sky colour)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, alternatively, use the [lerpColor()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/lerpColor) function, which will help you make a smooth transition between colors. Since `lerpColor` will change from one defined color to another, I would change the boundaries of the time intervals to represent the time of the day where the correspondent color is the "purest" (midnight is the "blackest", noon is the "bluest", etc)

I took the liberty of rewriting some of your code to make a snippet you can check. In it you can control the time of the day with a slider and see the color change.

```js
const slider = document.getElementById('slider')
const label = document.getElementById('sliderValue')
slider.oninput = handleChange

function handleChange(event){
  cMin = event.target.value
  sliderValue.innerText = parseInt(cMin/60)+"h / "+cMin + "m"
  
  setColours()
}

const black = [0, 0, 0]
const purple = [88, 52, 133]
const orange = [232, 131, 72]
const blue = [45, 221, 227]

let cMin
let hr
let currentColor

function setup(){
  createCanvas(300, 50)
  background(black)
}

function setColours(){
 
 hr = cMin / 60;
 
 if(hr >= 0 && hr <= 4.5){
   currentColor = lerpSkyColor(black, purple, 0, 4.5)
 }
 
 if(hr > 4.5 && hr <= 5.5){
   currentColor = lerpSkyColor(purple, orange, 4.5, 5.5)
 }
 
 if(hr > 5.5 && hr <= 12){
   currentColor = lerpSkyColor(orange, blue, 5.5, 12)
 }
 
 if(hr > 12 && hr <= 18.5){
   currentColor = lerpSkyColor(blue, orange, 12, 18.5)
 }
 
 if(hr > 18.5 && hr <= 19.5){
   currentColor = lerpSkyColor(orange, purple, 18.5, 19.5)
 }
 
 if(hr > 19.5 && hr <= 24){
   currentColor = lerpSkyColor(purple, black, 19.5, 24)
 }
 
 background(currentColor)
}

function lerpSkyColor(from, to, startTime, endTime){
  const lerpAmt = map(hr, startTime, endTime, 0, 1)
  return lerpColor(color(from), color(to), lerpAmt)
}
```

```css
#slider{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.min.js"></script>

<h2 id="sliderValue">0h / 0m</h2>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="1440" value="1"/>
```

You can, also, adjust the time intervals in the if/else portion of the `setColours` method to better reflect the real color changes and keep a color the same for a period of time (maybe start to change from blue to orange at 17H instead of 12h)

```
if(hr > 12 && hr <=17){
  currentColor = blue
}
if(hr > 17 && hr <= 18.5){
  currentColor = lerpSkyColor(blue, orange, 17, 18.5)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the canvas to cycle through black -> purple -> orange -> blue -> orange -> purple -> black the `if` `else` cases can be simplified. We can also make the code easier to read by creating color constants that are indexes into the pallete.

To get the number of minutes until the next color change we can just subtract the current hour we are on from the next hour boundary and multiply by 60.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1120, 630);
  frameRate(60);
}
var mn = 0;
function draw() {
if (mn > 1439)
  mn = 0;
  mn++;
  setColours();
}

function setColours(){
  var black = 0;
  var orange = 1;
  var purple = 2;
  var blue = 3;
  var pallete = [color(0),color(232, 131, 72),color(88,52,133),color(45, 221, 227)];
 // let hr = mn/60.0; // will also work instead of map
  let hr = map(mn,0,1440,0,23);
  if (hr < 4){
    background(pallete[black]);
    console.log("Minutes until color change " + ((4 - hr)*60)); 
  } else if (hr < 6){
    background(pallete[purple]);
    console.log("Minutes until color change " + ((6 - hr)*60)); 
  } else if (hr < 8){
    background(pallete[orange]);
    console.log("Minutes until color change " + ((8 - hr)*60)); 
  } else if (hr < 16){
    background(pallete[blue]);
    console.log("Minutes until color change " + ((16 - hr)*60)); 
  } else if (hr < 18){
    background(pallete[orange]);
    console.log("Minutes until color change " + ((18 - hr)*60)); 
  } else if (hr < 20){
    background(pallete[purple]);
    console.log("Minutes until color change " + ((20 - hr)*60)); 
  } else {
     background(pallete[black]);
     // here we subtract our hour from 28 to account for the 4 hours at the beginning
     console.log("Minutes until color change " + ((28- hr)*60)); 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```